# How can i disable cashing in jsp without scriptlets?

Tags: jsp, caching

i know that we can disable jsp caching using

```
<%
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setdateHeader("Expires", 0);
%>
```

but i am looking for doing this inside jsp file without scriplets

Comment: if i understand correctly you can try with html it self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```